# check string for AlphaNumeric word and convert to uppercase using VB

Tags: excel, vba

I am after suggestions on how to identify an alphanumeric word in a string, extract the word, convert to uppercase, then replace the word back into the string.

Example:
`Free Standing Oven or90sdbgfx2 Brushed Stainless Steel`

Would be converted to:
`Free Standing Oven OR90SDBGFX2 Brushed Stainless Steel`

The words location could be anywhere within the string and there could be multiple alphanumeric words in the string.

Comment: if the words can be anywhere and any number of times, what makes them unique?? Alpha-numeric combination??

Comment: If a word contains one number,  all its letters need to be convert into uppercase? What should the function return,  just a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve your problem-

```
Sub Main()
    Dim longString, result As String
    Dim arrayString() As String
    Set objRegExp_1 = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    objRegExp_1.Pattern = "((?:[a-z][a-z]*[0-9]+[a-z0-9]*))" 'REGEX for alphanumeric words in the string
    longString = "Free Standing Oven or90sdbgfx2 Brushed Stainless Steel"
    arrayString = Split(longString, " ") 'Splits the string into an array of words so that each one can be matched with the REGEX pattern to check if its alphanumeric
    For i = 0 To UBound(arrayString)
        Set regExp_Matches = objRegExp_1.Execute(arrayString(i))
        If regExp_Matches.Count = 1 Then
            arrayString(i) = UCase(arrayString(i)) 'If a pattern match is found, the corresponding string is converted to uppercase and stored back
        End If
    Next
    result = Join(arrayString, " ") 'Combines elements of the modified array of words into a single string
    MsgBox (result)
End Sub
```

**Input**:

`Free Standing Oven or90sdbgfx2 Brushed Stainless Steel`

**Output**:

`Free Standing Oven OR90SDBGFX2 Brushed Stainless Steel`

Comment: Thank you CRACKC for your fast and amazing response. When I add this to my Excel 2013 code I receive a Syntax error at the "Dim r as New Regex(regex1)" line. I have gone into the projects references and added in Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5 with no change in the Syntax error?

Comment: @Michael - that's because this is .NET code, not VBA.

Comment: @Comintern thanx for the info. Actually, i wrote the code in VS2010 and there I was getting error with `Dim regex As RegExp`. So i switched to `Dim r As New Regex(regex1)`. Had no idea that it wouldn't run inside Excel.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to the regular expression used (credit for that goes to @CRAKC). Here is the VBA implementation:

```
Sub VBASample()
    Dim tokens() As String
    Dim regex As RegExp
    Dim idx As Integer

    tokens = Split("Free Standing Oven or90sdbgfx2 Brushed Stainless Steel", " ")

    Set regex = New RegExp
    With regex
        .Pattern = "((?:[a-z][a-z]*[0-9]+[a-z0-9]*))"
        For idx = 0 To UBound(tokens)
            If .Test(tokens(idx)) Then
                tokens(idx) = UCase$(tokens(idx))
            End If
        Next idx
    End With

    Debug.Print Join$(tokens, " ")
End Sub
```

You'll need a reference to Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5.

Comment: A huge Thank you to all you assisted especially @CRACKC & Comintern. Your assistance is greatly appreciated. I never cease to be amazed at what can be done with VB Code. I always know that if I need to look for assistance this site, "Stackoverflow.com" is the place to look. This is the first time I have not been able to find assistance in the existing questions. The response I have received has been outstanding Thank you.

Comment: This is how I am using the code. 
`Sub FindAlphaNum(Description As String)
    Dim tokens() As String
    Dim regex As RegExp
    Dim idx As Integer

    tokens = Split(Description, " ")
    Set regex = New RegExp
    With regex
        .Pattern = "((?:[a-z][a-z]*[0-9]+[a-z0-9]*))"
        For idx = 0 To UBound(tokens)
            If .Test(tokens(idx)) Then
                tokens(idx) = UCase$(tokens(idx))
            End If
        Description = Join$(tokens, " ")
        Next idx
    End With
End Sub`